# Verification of adding an identical record in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need support, I have a procedure and I need it to return an error when I try to add the same name in the ProductName column:

```
USE [Northwind]
        GO
        /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[AddNewProduct]    Script Date: 14.09.2021 18:15:53 ******/
        SET ANSI_NULLS ON
        GO
        SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
        GO
        ALTER procedure [dbo].[AddNewProduct]
        
        @ProductName nvarchar(40), @SupplierID int, @CategoryID int, @QuantityPerUnit nvarchar(20), @UnitPrice money, @UnitsInStock smallint, @UnitsOnOrder smallint, @ReorderLevel smallint, @Discontinued bit
        as
        
        If @ProductName = @ProductName
        
        Begin 
            Declare  @count int, @ProductID int 
        
            
        
            Insert into Products
                (
                
                ProductName ,
                SupplierID ,
                CategoryID ,
                QuantityPerUnit,
                UnitPrice,
                UnitsInStock,
                UnitsOnOrder,
                ReorderLevel,
                Discontinued)
                
                
                values
                (@ProductName, 
                @SupplierID , 
                @CategoryID , 
                @QuantityPerUnit, 
                @UnitPrice, 
                @UnitsInStock, 
                @UnitsOnOrder, 
                @ReorderLevel, 
                @Discontinued )
        
        
        End 
        
        else
        Begin
            DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
            SET @ErrorMessage = 'DDDD';
            RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, 16, 1);
        end
```

I want a message to appear when I try to add the same record
Can you tell me what I am doing wrong or what needs to be added / changed?

Comment: Why write code (that doesn't work apparently) when a unique constraint does that effortlessly?

Comment: `If @ProductName = @ProductName` - eh?

Comment: `If @ProductName = @ProductName`? Why not `IF @ProductName IS NOT NULL` as that's the *only* time the prior would be `FALSE`, and it's far more intuitive.

Comment: You *aren't* the author? Then why aren't they fixing their mess?

Comment: But what @SMor said *is* the solution; this isn't something to handle in your procedure, it should be handled by a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`/`UNIQUE INDEX`.

Comment: It is different what a procedure should look like, which does not allow adding the same record name.

Comment: Again proper use of constraints solves this mess pretty easily. And if you want it to return error messages why not use try/catch instead? I mean thats what its intended for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, this logic has no right being in the procedure, it should be part of the table's definition, as a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` or `UNIQUE INDEX`. I'm going to use a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` here, which would mean the DDL for the `CONSTRAINT` would look like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.Products ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_ProductName UNIQUE (ProductName);
```

Then, you just need your procedure to look like this:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddNewProduct] @ProductName nvarchar(40),
                                      @SupplierID int,
                                      @CategoryID int,
                                      @QuantityPerUnit nvarchar(20), --Why is this an nvarchar if it's a quantity?
                                      @UnitPrice money,
                                      @UnitsInStock smallint,
                                      @UnitsOnOrder smallint,
                                      @ReorderLevel smallint,
                                      @Discontinued bit AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Products(ProductName,
                             SupplierID,
                             CategoryID,
                             QuantityPerUnit,
                             UnitPrice,
                             UnitsInStock,
                             UnitsOnOrder,
                             ReorderLevel,
                             Discontinued)
    VALUES (@ProductName, @SupplierID, @CategoryID, @QuantityPerUnit, @UnitPrice, @UnitsInStock, @UnitsOnOrder, @ReorderLevel, @Discontinued);        
END;
GO
```

If you then attempt to insert a duplicate value you'll get the following error:

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ_ProductName'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Products'. The duplicate key value is ({Duplicate Product Name}).

Comment: Thanks Larnu I forgot that add Unique key value column ProductName